# Determine the proportion of the data information in r

Tags: r, distribution, point

Suppose i have a plot like the following:
[image]

I want to get the portion of the data where the majority (say 90%) of the data lay, for example, i want to isolate the plot into something like:
[image]
in which the points lay in the black frame contributes to (90%) of the data.

How can i do this in R?

Edited for comment:
What if i have the following plot:? the majority part probably start from 0.
[image]

Comment: I assume you want to find a 90 % interquantile range. Thus, simply calculate the 5 % and 95 % quantiles of your x-values. See `help("quantile")`.

Comment: @Roland i've added addition information in the question, like 90% IQR may work, but there're cases where the majority of the data points actually lay at the very beginning.

Comment: 90 % is 90 %. There is not one interval that gives you 90 % data coverage, there are usually many. You can of course choose to start the interval at 0 % but that is an arbitrary decision. Also, why are you doing this? Is this perhaps a misguided attempt to exclude extreme values from regression analysis?

Comment: @Roland Basically, i have hundreds of plots like the ones given in the question. I want to remove the "tails" of the data and get only the "core" of the data. Like the flowing points contain no/very few information in comparison to the data.

Comment: Well, I guess it's slightly better to remove data from plots than from the models but it is still misleading. At least indicate to the reader that part of the data is not plotted. (As a reviewer I would recommend rejection for any manuscript that does this.)

Comment: @Roland true, but the problem is, i've hundreds of these plot, i can't really manually remove the points, so i want to find the location of the core data and maybe say, remove all other data points that exist out of the core.